# Disable reorder on frozen columns in DataTables

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

I enabled the re-order option on my table and works fine except there's a detail I need to get rid of.

I have a frozen column to the right with tools to manage the row. My table allows to scroll left right and have those tools easily accessible.

It seems DataTables creates another table cloned from the main one when creating this frozen column.

Here's the initialization for the table:

```
scope.TableData = $('#tableData').DataTable({
    rowReorder: {
        selector: 'td:first-child',
        update: false,
    },
    paging: true,
    fixedColumns: {
        rightColumns: 1,
        leftColumns: 0
    },
    select: {
        style: 'os',
        selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
    },
    "search": {
        "regex": true
    },
    order: [[1, 'asc']],
    'filter': true,
    'scrollX': true,
    'bInfo': true,
    'scrollCollapse': true,
    scroller: {
        rowHeight: 20
    },
    'columnDefs': [
        { className: 'select-checkbox', targets: 1 },
        { className: 'reorder', targets: 0, orderable: true },
        { orderable: false, targets: -1 }
    ],
    "order": [],
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "language": {
        "lengthMenu": "@Html.ResStr("DataRowLengthMenu")",
        "zeroRecords": "@Html.ResStr("DataRowEmpty")",
        "info": "@Html.ResStr("DataRowInfo")",
        "infoEmpty": "@Html.ResStr("DataRowEmpty")",
        "infoFiltered": "@Html.ResStr("DataRowFilter")",
        "search": "",
        "processing": "<span style=\"color: dodgerblue; font-weight: bold;\">@Html.ResStr("PleaseWait")</span>",
        "lengthMenu": "@Html.ResStr("DataRowLengthMenu")<br><br>",
        "paginate": {
            "next": "@Html.ResStr("DataRowNext")",
            "previous": "@Html.ResStr("DataRowPrevious")"
        },
        select: {
            rows: {
                _: "@Html.ResStr("DataRowsSelected")",
                0: "",
                1: "@Html.ResStr("DataRowSelected")"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

(Don't mind `@Html.ResStr`, the javascript is in an ASP MVC view)

Here's an animated GIF of the problem:

[image]

As you can see, works fine when dragging the row via the "Seq" column, but I can't click the buttons in the frozen column because it triggers a drag event.

Here's a fiddle that has the issue. Click on the buttons on the rows, you'll see.

https://jsfiddle.net/1qod8mLx/2/

Comment: Can we have a usable example to work with?

Comment: @Deckerz added it

Comment: Did you try adding `event.stopPropagation()` to the button click or mousedown events?

Comment: @ratherblue It happens when clicking anything in those cells, not just the buttons though. I could try that at a higher level perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the selected from `td:first-child` to `td[name="reorder"]` as the select. And in the HTML added `name="reorder"` on the `td` you wanted, this way allows you to apply the drag on any `td` you want.

```
var table = $('#tableData').DataTable({
    rowReorder: {
      selector: 'td[name="reorder"]',
      update: false,
    },
    paging: true,
    fixedColumns: {
      rightColumns: 1,
      leftColumns: 0
    },
    select: {
      style: 'os',
      selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
    },
    "search": {
      "regex": true
    },
    'filter': true,
    'scrollX': true,
    'bInfo': true,
    'scrollCollapse': true,
    scroller: {
      rowHeight: 20
    },
    'columnDefs': [{
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets: 1
      },
      {
        className: 'reorder',
        targets: 0,
        orderable: true
      },
      {
        orderable: false,
        targets: -1
      }
    ],
    "order": []
  });
```

Example row in table:

```
     <tr>
        <td name="reorder">1</td>
        <td style="line-height: 20px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle;"></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lead</td>
        <td>#1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
        <td>a@a.com</td>
        <td>444-333-2222</td>
        <td align="center" style="background-color: #e6e6e6;vertical-align: middle">
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-edit-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-delete-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>

        </td>
      </tr>
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lfrxujgv/